# sqlite select query on ionic app is not working

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

```
db=$cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"storyDB.db",iosDatabaseLocation:'default'});
var Emp_code = '599c0011486bbc0673fefcc4';
var query = "select * from  kidapp_audio  WHERE storyid = '" + Emp_code + "'";
try {
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        }, function (err) {
             console.error(err);
    });
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Use SQLite for an ionic app development. insert query working correctly. Record exist with this `storyid  599c0011486bbc0673fefcc4`. But running select query shows an error "unfortunately, appname has stopped. How can I solve this?

Comment: post your error report and tell me

Comment: No error is shown only message shown is app crashed

Comment: There will be some logs in logcat. Please post those errors?